# OkHttp route traffic throw wifi and SocketFactory

Tags: android, okhttp, android-networking

I need to route specific requests throw wifi, even wifi "Connected, no internet" and "Mobile Data" is turned On.

Below example works fine with `HttpURLConnection`, but not works with OkHttp3 (3.8.1) which is primary network library for app:

Code below works as expected with OkHttp version: **3.4.2**

But broken since OkHttp version: **3.5.0**

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        final Network[] networks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();

        for (final Network network : networks) {
            final NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
            if (netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI && netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

             // just for example HttpURLConnection works as expected and route traffic throw wifi
             connection = (HttpURLConnection) network.openConnection(url);

             // not works since >=3.5.0, route traffic in same way
             builder.socketFactory(network.getSocketFactory());

            }
        }
    }

OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
final Response response = client.newCall(initialRequest).execute();
```

client.newCall not works as expected as I understand, or I simple missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/commit/2a5fb08b39195d4238c7117e851e9221f94de62a#diff-ec23bee7240c28053b0ca4fbc6029529

So if you want to get the old behaviour (like in 3.4.2 version) back you can take java.net.ProxySelector.getDefault() and wrap it with one that also tries NO_PROXY.

In my case, described above, i need to manually disable proxy before add socketFactory:

```
builder.proxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
builder.socketFactory(network.getSocketFactory());
```