# Failed to connect to local IP for External Device (Camera) with WIFI using OkHttp

Tags: android, kotlin, ip, local, okhttp

I have a **[360 Insta Camera](https://www.insta360.com/)** that connects with `WIFI` to an android phone using `OKHttp` and Should connect to `Local Ip (192.....)`!

**Problem:**

When both mobile data and wifi are enabled, in android 11 and 12, when the user enables the `Automatic Switch connection` Option, the OS set priority for `Mobile Data` and The problem happened! The camera can not connect to the phone because when the device has internet, It looks for IP in the network!

How Can I fix this problem with `OKHttp`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pin the network with something like the following

[OkHttp route traffic throw wifi and SocketFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953968/okhttp-route-traffic-throw-wifi-and-socketfactory)

```
        final Network[] networks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();

        for (final Network network : networks) {
            final NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
            if (netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI && netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

             // just for example HttpURLConnection works as expected and route traffic throw wifi
             connection = (HttpURLConnection) network.openConnection(url);

             // not works since >=3.5.0, route traffic in same way
             builder.socketFactory(network.getSocketFactory());

            }
        }
```